# how to display chart.js legend with different bar color

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

i have a code here: http://jsfiddle.net/emo_noel10/5ztuvLwc/10/

```
var barData = {
    labels: ["Prk. Atis", "Prk. Avocado", "Prk. Bayabas", "Prk. Boongon", "Prk. Chico", "Prk. Durian", "Prk. Guyabano", "Prk. Kaimito", "Prk. Kasoy", "Prk. Lanzones", "Prk. Lomboy", "Prk. Mabolo", "Prk. Macopa", "Prk. Mangga", "Prk. Mangosteen", "Prk. Mansanas", "Prk. Marang", "Prk. Marang Joesil", "Prk. Melon", "Prk. Nangka", "Prk. Pomelo", "Prk. Rambutan", "Prk. Santol", "Prk. Sereguellas", "Prk. Sunkist", "Prk. Tambis", "Prk. Ubas", "Fishpond/Sea wall"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [20, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 20, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 20, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 20, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]
};

var barDataOption = {
    responsive: true,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    scaleShowGridLines: true,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    animateRotate: true,
    animateScale: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
    legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
};

var puroksBarData = document.getElementById("totalPopulationByPurok").getContext("2d");
new Chart(puroksBarData).Bar(barData, barDataOption);
```

i am so curious since i get the bar graph with different colors, it is possible that it will display a legend by its bar with its designated color just like the chart.js pie and doughnut charts?

Any help and suggestions is heavenly appreciated, TIA.

Comment: @halfer you have a idea about this? if you are, please help.. thanks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have modified the library code to generate different colors using your own function, you can use the same function to generate the legend, like so (at the end of your script)

```
var legendHTML = '';
barData.labels.forEach(function(label, i) {
    legendHTML += ('<li><span style="background: ' + getFillColor(i) + '"></span>' + label + '</li>');
})
document.getElementById("totalPopulationByPurokLegend").innerHTML = '<ul class="chartLegend">' + legendHTML + '</ul>';
```

with CSS

```
.chartLegend {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-color: #666;
}

.chartLegend span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You don't need the `legendTemplate` option by the way.

Comment: i see, i thought it would work like the same thing at the docs. Thank you so much @potatopeelings :)
kudos! (y)

Comment: btw @potatopeelings, how to display their values beside their  designated legend?

Comment: nevermind, i get it now. i use this:

`var legendHTML = '';
                barData.labels.forEach(function(label, i) {
                    barData.datasets.forEach(function(value) {
                        legendHTML += ('<li><span style="background: ' + getFillColor(i) + '"></span>' + label + ': </li>' + value['data'][i] + '<br>');
                    });
                });
                document.getElementById("totalPopulationByPurokLegend").innerHTML = '<ul class="bar-legend">' + legendHTML + '</ul>';`

tnx once again :)